# Bootstrap 3.2.0 and accounts management in Meteor.js 0.9.1: not working at all

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm using `mizzao:bootstrap-3`, `accounts-password` and `mrt:accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown`. I need to integrate the basic user management in my app, but I can't get the {{> loginButtons}} working at all: it doesn't display anything. This is the sample code I'm working on (the usual sample actually):

```
<template name="header">
<header class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        Chat me
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li>{{> loginButtons align="right"}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
</template>
```

If I remove `mizzao:bootstrap-3` and I use `meteor add bootstrap` it works, but the in this case bootstrap version is 1.0.0 (too old fro my needs).
Any ideas?

Comment: Try updating to 0.9.1.1, does it help? They've tried to fix this. Also do you get any errors on your server console/browser console about anything being undefined or incompatible packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the popular `mizzao:bootstrap-3` is incomplete. Luckily, you can now install the officially supported package:

```
meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

See their [GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) for verification

Answer (score 0):

I use this package mrt:bootstrap-3. I don't have problems with it.